# making a key value pair in array but array does not count it as an element

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.length)
arr.greet = 'Hi';
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.length)
console.log(arr.pop())
```

As the title said, compiler doesn't see `greet` as an element of array `arr`. The length is same and `arr.pop()` returns `5`. Why

Edit- second `console.log(arr)` prints `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, greet: 'Hi']` when running in console of browser but not showing the same in code snippet runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) are *exotic* objects with own properties and methods. Only  keys which are positive 32 bit integers counts as length.

You could get the entries for getting all own ennumerable keys with values.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.greet = 'Hi';

console.log(Object.entries(arr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`greet` is a property of `arr`.

You can get it like this:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3]
array.someProp = 'prop'

console.log(array.someProp)

// but the array looks normal
console.log(array)
```

But if you need to push some value to array use this:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3]

array.push('42')

console.log(array)

// here you can get the last item of array

const lastItem = array.pop()

console.log(lastItem)
```

Comment: Can I push a key-value pair and expect the same?

Comment: You can push an object: `array.push({foo: 'bar'})`

Answer (score 1):

Because you have just added another property to the object. It is no different than

```
let obj = {};
obj.greet = 'Hi';
```

and then expecting that generic object to become an array with length 1. JavaScript objects are dynamic and can have properties dynamically added to them, doesn't matter if they have been instantiated from a specific prototype such as Array, you can still stick any property you want on any object.